# statistics find $(2X<Y)$ for $e^{-x+y}$ for $0<x<y<\infty$

Tags: probability, statistics

I tried to solve the following problem without success:

> Let $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} k e^{-(x+y)} & \text{for } 0 < x < y < \infty \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>   Find $P(2X < Y)$

k=2

My attempt:

$2x$ is smaller than $y$ for half of $x$ that is for start of $y$ divided by $2$
$$
2 \int_0^{y/2} e^{-(x+y)} \, \mathrm{d} x = 2 \int_0^{y/2} e^{-x} e^{-y} \, \mathrm{d} x
= 2e^{-y} \int_0^{y/2} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d} x = 2 e^{-y} \left[ e^{-x} \right]_0^{y/2} = 2 e^{-y}\left( e^{-y/2} - 1 \right) \\
= 2e^{-y-y/2} - e^{-y}
$$

The answer sheet's solution:
$$
P(2X \le Y) = \int_0^\infty \int_{2x}^\infty 2 e^{-(x+y)} \, \mathrm{d} y \, \mathrm{d} x 
= 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \left( \int_{2x}^\infty e^{-y} \, \mathrm{d} y \right) \, \mathrm{d} x \\
= 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-x}e^{-2x} \, \mathrm{d} x = 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-3x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{2}{3}
$$

Why is what I have done wrong? And why is the answer sheet correct? Especially how does the answer find the limits of integration, and is there any way to check to see if the answer you get is correct given that you know that you must find 2X

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right away you should see that your solution is wrong (at least I did). When you want to find the probability of some event that specifies what $X$ and $Y$ must be then you should get a number, not some expression involving $y$. For instance if they asked for the marginal probability meaning $P(X \le 5 \mid Y)$ then indeed the answer would depend on $y$.

The answer sheet is correct because you're attempting to find
$$
P(2X \le Y) = P(\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid 2x \le y \}) = \int_{\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 2x \le y \}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d} A
$$

In order to think about problems like this it helps to visualize the set over which you're integrating. If we know that $2x \le y$ then we can plot $y = 2x$ and see that the portion of the graph where this is true is above that line. Now how do we integrate over this region? This is a multivariable question, but I'll try to provide as much help as I can.

Note that if we first hold $y$ constant then $0 < x \le \frac{1}{2} y$ and then following we get that $0 < y < \infty$. Using this characterization of our set we see that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 2x \le y \}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d} A & = & \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{y/2} 2e^{-(x+y)} \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} y \\
& = & 2\int_0^\infty e^{-y} \left( e^0 - e^{-y/2} \right) \, \mathrm{d} y \\
& = & 2 \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-y} \, \mathrm{d} y - \int_0^\infty e^{-3/2y} \, \mathrm{d} y \right) \\
& = & 2 \left( 1 - \frac{2}{3} \right) = \frac{2}{3}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now of course you can characterize the set as the answer guide did and integrate over $y$ first and $x$ second, as you can see your limits simply change.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it did definitely help to get a clearer picture! I will use the area approach as it makes sense to get a picture of all outcomes. Thanks a lot:):)

Comment: @Tor no problem, if you think this post answers your question then mark it as so so that the question gets closed. Welcome to the site by the way ;D